# Enter dynamically loaded (in ajax) data into database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Form :

```
<form  id="regd" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" action="register_action.php">
    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="26" name="txtname" required="required" />     </td></tr>
        <tr>
    <td>Em@il id</td>
    <td><input type="email" size="26" name="txtemail" required="required" /> </td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" size="26" name="pwd1" required="required"> </td></tr>


            <tr> <td>Country</td>
    <td><div><select  required="true" name="country" id="country">
<option value="">Select Country</option>

<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

<option value=<?php echo $row['country_id']?>"<?php echo  $row['country_name']?>"><?php echo $row['country_name']?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select></div> </td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>State/td>
    <td>
    <div id="statediv">
    <input name="state"  type="text" maxlength="255" value="" required="required" title="Select Country first"/> 
</div> 
</td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input id="btn_cancel" type="reset" value="Cancel" class="regdbutton"></td>
 <td><input id="btn_submit" type="submit" /></td></tr>
</form>
```

Here is the form , where I want to enter the values to the database, and it is entering also without that state, which has been getting loaded through Ajax.. Below is the code (I've skipped that function XmlHTTP thing because that is making the code longer)

Ajax Part :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getState(countryid) {      
var strURL="findState.php?country="+countryid;
var req = getXMLHTTP(); 
if (req) {  
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (req.readyState == 4) {
if (req.status == 200)     {                        
                         document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
                    document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML='<select name="city">'+
                    '<option>Select City</option>'+
                    '</select>';                        
} else {
alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
}
}               
}           
req.open("GET", strURL, true);
req.send(null);
}       
}
</script>
```

Find City:

```
<?php $country=intval($_GET['country']);
include("config.php");
$query="SELECT state_id,state_name FROM state WHERE country_id='$country'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>
<select style="width:190px;" class="element select medium" name="state" onchange="getCity(<?php echo $country?>,this.value)" title="State">
<option>Select State</option>
<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?php echo $row['state_id']?>"<?php echo $row['state_name']?>"><?php echo $row['state_name']?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

I didn't post my action code because it's working fine with an error "undefined index state" and the value is not entering.

Comment: What is your code doing after pressing submit button? You said you are getting an error _undefined index..._ which can be something belongs to your ajax submit.

Comment: no m just using normal action page for it.. @user3280126

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, it's not clear where you are getting error; after submitting the form and then on script or on submitting or when loading data? _Its working fine with an error_ makes me a bit curious.

Comment: just my state value is not getting inserted to the database but the others are